# My account was extended after I quit instead of terminated

Tags: resignation

At the last working day of my job, I heard that someone requested to extend my accounts to login to some application servers and to my mailbox as well, and the reason given was to support for some coming system upgrade. It sounds not a good reason as to get the access to servers, the normal way is to submit request and get the authorization. The IT policy usually does not allow using other people’s accounts. I am not sure if there is an exception for the left employee. Just wondering whether this is common and I am too nervous?

Comment: Are you nervous that people will accuse you of hacking in after you left?

Comment: Did you give them the passwords to those accounts?

Comment: Do you have some specific thing you're worried about, or is it just general concern?

Comment: If you gave them the passwords to your account then that was probably against IT policy. You should get that sorted.

Comment: Thanks so much all of you replying me. I am new to here and did not figure out how to reply to individuals so I wrote down here.. no I did not give them the password. They reset my password after I left. And it is just a general concern, not for a particular thing. There were no personal emails in the company mailbox, just not feel well if someone reading all my emails for some reason I did not know.

Comment: If you did not speak with the company head of security on your way out the door, you need to speak with him/her RIGHT NOW.  Topic of discussion: reminder that you terminated your employment on such-and-such date, and you just learned that your computer accounts were still in existence.  Emphasize that you have NOT attempted to log in (and DON'T TRY IT!) to see if the passwords were changed, but you need him/her to verify, for safety, that the passwords WERE changed on that date.  (If they weren't, you are potentially open to finding yourself in a world of hurt.)  Continued on next rock...

Comment: Regardless of whether you actually speak (by phone or in person) with the head of security, send him/her a letter, BY REGISTERED MAIL (Registered, not Certified), including all of the above information.  The letter will almost certainly be routed through Corporate Legal, as Registered Mail items are almost always warning shots fired shortly before litigation is filed.  The key is to ensure that you DO NOT even inadvertently still have access to anything, AND that they have been formally notified in a legally-admissible way that you do not have any access.

Answer (score 16):

This isn't your problem, you have left.

It's fairly normal to rename an employees logins, this ensures their replacements gets the correct access to do the work without the need to rebuild a profile. Same goes for mail.

But none of it is your concern, especially on vague hearsay.

Comment: +1 I was just about to write a very similar answer - it's definitly not best practise but very common in such cases when the replacements haven't been set up yet and shouldn't concern the OP..

Comment: @iLuvLogix yes Kilisi's wisdom is valued

Comment: @Killisi  reusing accounts is very bad security practice and should not be done expect in extreme urgency.

Comment: @Neuromancer rubbish.... little difference between renaming a profile and changing the password, vrs making a new profile. Plenty of benefits to doing so which is why it's standard practice in many places. The first takes a few minutes and keeps all security hierarchy settings intact, the second can take much longer and can require a higher level of security depending on set up..

Answer (score 2):

This would be very weird.

As employee you had ane of more roles. This would be marked with accoringly with one of more roles assigned to your IT profile. Someone who takes over your work would get access to these roles. **Not to your account, to the relevant roles**

If there is any relevent information for that role I expect it to be stored on a shared drive, a mailbox extract (e.g. in an .pst) or forwarded to whomever needs access to replace you. This has probably been most of the work which you have been doing in the last week(s) of your job.

I would **never** expect someone to use your account unless it is a function account likle salesperson1@firm.tld.  I regular account should be blocked the day after you left. Never extended (ecept for out of office email with an out of office message abnd most certainly never receive a password reset unless you failed to trainfer relevant work files.

Caveeat: I aam assumling a normal (aka good) leave of the job with a proper transfer of knowlege and data to a replacement. Not some weird USA style "you are fired. We walk you to the exit. Sucks if you have any coworkers" kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Is it common for employers to keep email accounts open? Yes, it's quite common especially if you are in IT or customer service role where emails are vital. For customers, obviously they want to forward emails to other team members, and for IT, you might get important script or jobs that others might want to fix or change.

As far as using it to log in to something, that's where it is a bit concerning. For one, log into what? An internal test system? Why can't they just create a user for themselves? What makes your user so special that they have to log in with it? A good example might be if you ordered a service using your email and they can't change the login since its tied to an email. For me, in my last job we had a director leave and he had an AWS account that we had to use his email to log in with.

Overall though it doesn't matter. You don't work there anymore. I would only be concerned if it is logging into a financial or HR system and I would email with a follow up asking why your name is used and bring up some obvious concerns with that. Obviously if someone sees Ciao changed someone's HR information after his departure date, that might raise some concerns and it would be hard for you to prove that you didn't especially if the system can be accessed outside their network.